# Can not ask question due to "This title does not meet our quality standards. "

Tags: support

My question is very simple, and I tried several title as below:

1. `listary command mkdir not working`
2. `listary command mkdir do not action`

The detail I want to post is:

> On Windows 7,  I use listary's build-in command `mkdir xxx` to create a `xxx` folder in current dir, but nothing happen.
>   This feature does support in free version, see official docs: http://www.listary.com/pro
>   . I can't figure out why it not working.

The question title is the exactly problem what I met, title is very clear, but I can't post it due to

> This title does not meet our quality standards. Please make sure that it clearly summarizes your problem and uses proper grammar. You can put details in the body of your question.

why?

Comment: Out of preference you should use a complete English sentence in your title rather than "x in y not working" you should aim for "Why does the command x not work in y?". We get a lot of lazy questions and they tend to get ignored, having a lazy title makes it more likely to not even be looked at in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's automated regex based checks for quality.

Try "The mkdir command does not do anything in listary"

While I'm critiquing stuff, I'd also suggest

> On Windows 7, I use listary's built-in `mkdir xxx` command to create a
>   xxx folder in current dir, but nothing happens. This feature is
>   supported in the free version according to the official documentation at http://www.listary.com/pro. There's no error message so I'd like to know how to make this work, and if not, why?

Comment: Thanks. The automated regex need improve, that tip is annoying when people post a valid title.

Comment: People have asked so many terrible questions with those words that... those checks have been found to work.